# TensorFLow Federated on Windows

Tags: windows, installation, tensorflow-federated

Can TensorFlow Federated be installed on Windows?
Documentation only describes Ubuntu and MacOS   https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/install

Answer (score 2):

TFF depends on Jax for supporting the experimental [`tff.experimental.jax_computation`](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/experimental/jax_computation) decorators. Jax unfortunately does not have Windows support (https://github.com/google/jax/issues/438), consequently through transitivity its unlikely TFF will work on windows at the moment.